# Android Studio Build Error Could not resolve all dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting the following error when I try to build an existing project using Android Studio.

My coworkers are able to build this project without these errors.

I am on a Macbook.

I already have added the following in my build.gradle

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }

org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:devDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:75)

...

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not determine artifacts for com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v1.0.1: Skipped due to earlier error
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.

changing to `maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }` (added `www.`) resolved the issue

here is the same question BTW:

[Android Studio maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } can't download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389211/android-studio-maven-url-https-jitpack-io-cant-download)

Comment: Ridicules problem... You made my day, and saved me hundreds of hours. Thanks