# React-native running first time

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

**I´m new in react-native and I´m trying to run my first Hello World project.
But I´m getting this error
How could I solve this?**

> info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can
> disable it using the "--no-jetifier" flag. Jetifier found 863 file(s) to
> forward-jetify. Using 4 workers... info Starting JS server... info
> Installing the app...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
>
> > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
> > Required by:
> > project : app
> > > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
> > > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jitpack.io/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Received status code 522 from server: Origin Connection Time-out
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with the --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 48s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
> development environment set up:
> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment.
> Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Error: Command failed:
> gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
>
> > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
> > Required by:
> > project:app
> > > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
> > > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jitpack.io/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Received status code 522 from server: Origin Connection Time-out
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with the --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 48s
>
> ```
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
> at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
> at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\amaro.manungu\AmaroProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
> at buildAndRun (C:\Users\amaro.manungu\AmaroProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
> at C:\Users\amaro.manungu\AmaroProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\amaro.manungu\AmaroProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
> ```

Comment: Did you run `react-native run-android` with internet connection?

Comment: Yes, I did run.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following in `android/build.gradle`

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

to

```
maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52812651/1889732

Answer (score 0):

build the project with offline mode.
you can toggle the offline mode button on in android studio.
if you build project use command line add --offline at the end of the gradle command.